# Clarification on setting up a self-hosted linux build server for azure pipeline jobs

Tags: azure-devops

I have successfully created an Azure pipeline job and connected it with a self-hosted linux (debian) build server.  The problem is that I can't get the agent to run as a service.  I have to ssh to the build server and run ~/myagent/run.sh manually.  When I run sudo ~/myagent/svc.sh start, it completes and says it's running, but jobs in the queue just wait until I ssh to the build server and execute ~/myagent/run.sh

Perhaps I haven't set the server up correctly.  I installed the following pieces:

Deployment Pool had an install script and I ran that.  It installed code at ~/azagent

Deployment Pool had an install script and I rant that.  It installed code at ~/azagent

Agent Pool had an install script.  I installed that at ~/myagent.

Comment: I created a new VM to test the install procedure.  This time, I did not install the Deployment pool nor deployment agent scripts. Rather, I installed just the agent pool code.  And that new vm is working fine.  I can successfully run sudo ~/myagent/svc.sh start and it pulls queued jobs from the pipeline.

I guess the install scripts for Deployment Pool and Deployment agents is what is confusing me.  I didn't install them this time and my build server is working.  When do you need to install them?

Comment: The deployment agent is probably for [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts).  In general, if you setup as an agent as a deployment agent, it will only pick up jobs in a release pipeline that are created under the deployment group phase.